# importing data from files on an ftp server directly into sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is it possible to import files from an ftp server directly into a sql server 2008 table using perhaps an SSIS package or something? I have thought of transferring the files via ftp to a local server and then doing the import but just wondered if there was more economical way of doing this with regards to space and memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the physical file location (i.e. you can map a drive to it) then yes you can bypass the FTP process.  If not, SSIS does not support ftp as a source connection within data flow.  You will need to use the FTP Task in the control flow to copy the file and then a File Source component within your Data Flow